# I want to edit xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader, xmltextwriter

[image]

I have modified the structure of d xml file. i want to edit value of visible

Comment: You need to expand this question with sample XML (before and after the change) to get a decent answer

Comment: The sample XML provide is not valid.  Tags c and d have no closing brace.

Comment: @Scott - nor does the second 'b'

Comment: its an example of the structure the issue is that i am unable to edit the attribute value from aaa to bb

Comment: @user428747: It's not an example of a valid XML file, which makes it hard to tell what the *correct* file would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such code pattern:

```
bool foobar()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.Load(FileName);
            XmlNodeList ns = doc.SelectNodes("a/d/e/f");
            if (ns.Count == 1)
            {

                    ns[0].Attributes["visible"].Value = true;
                    doc.Save(FileName);
                    return (true);
            }
            else
                return (false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return (false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using true/false instead of exceptions is a highly non-idiomatic (and lossy) way of indicating success or failure in .NET. Exceptions are there for a reason - use them!

Comment: Do you mean that i should populate exception to parent code? And what about performance in this situation?

Answer (score 6):

Well, LINQ to XML makes it very easy to manipulate XML documents, assuming they're small enough to be sensibly loaded into memory.

For example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Foo.xml");
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("c"))
{
    element.SetAttributeValue("value", "bb");
}
doc.Save("Bar.xml");
```

Now that will set the `value` attribute for *every* `c` element. It's not clear whether or not that's what you want. If it's not, please edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: Actually for it to work("SetAttribute" does not exist), use that code: element.SetAttributeValue("value", "bb");

Comment: Unbelievable I found a Jon Skeet mistake :)